# How to solve $2y′′+8y′+80y=F(t), y(0)=0, y′(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the initial value problem, $2y′′+8y′+80y=F(t),   y(0)=0,   y′(0)=0$ where $F(t)=20e^{-t}$ But I am unable to do it. I got the answer of $2Ae^{-t}=20e^{-t}$ But this is wrong I think.

I solved the complementary equation and got: $y_{c}=e^{-2t}Acos(6t)+Bsin(6t))$

For the particular solution I guessed (correctly I think) $y_{p}=Ae^{-t}$ Then working some derivates I got: $2Ae^{-t}-8Ae^{-t}+80Ae^{-t}$ I plugged 0 into the corresponding initial values given but this does not produce the right answer. Thank you for you help I got a test tomorrow. This was the only part I neglected -.-

Comment: you could use variation of parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2y′′+8y′+80y=F(t),   y(0)=0,   y′(0)=0$$
For the homogeneous I got this
$$2y′′+8y′+80y=0$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$r^2+4r+40=0$$
$$(r+2)^2-36i^2=0 \implies (r+2+6i)(r+2-6i)=0$$
$$\implies r=-2\pm 6i$$
Therefore the solution is
$$y_h=e^{-2t}(c_1\cos(6t)+c_2\sin(6t))$$
For the particular solution your guess is correct $y_p=Ae^{-t}$
$$2Ae^{-t}-8Ae^{-t}+80Ae^{-t}=20e^{-t}$$
$$74Ae^{-t}=20e^{-t} \implies A=\frac {10}{37}$$
$$y_p=e^{-t}\frac {10}{37}$$
$$y(t)=e^{-2t}(c_1\cos(6t)+c_2\sin(6t))+\frac {10}{37}e^{-t}$$
Apply the initial conditions ...I got this
$$(c_1,c_2)=(-\frac {10}{37},-\frac 5{111})$$
Finally,
$$y(t)=e^{-2t}(-\frac {10}{37}\cos(6t)-\frac 5{111}\sin(6t))+\frac {10}{37}e^{-t}$$

Answer (score 1):

$y_c= C_1 e^{-2t}\cos 6t + C_2 e^{-2t}\sin 6t\\
y_p = Ae^{-t}\\
2Ae^{−t}−8Ae^{−t}+80Ae^{−t}=F(t)=20e^{−t}\\
74A = 20\\
A = \frac {20}{74}\\
y(0) = C_1 + A = 0\\
C_1 = -\frac {20}{74}\\
y'(0) = -2C_1 + 6C_2 - A = 0$